# SVG splash screen image too big (and not scaling)

Tags: swift, svg, swiftui, splash-screen

I have the required attributes for a splash screen setup in my Info.plist file in Xcode 12.5.1, namely the "Launch Screen" dictionary and the "Image Name" value inside it. I'm using an SVG image as my image for this - however, when I'm loading up the application, the image is far too big, and goes off the screen. (See screenshot)

The SVG has the following in its top section:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 2000 2000" style="enable-background:new 0 0 2000 2000;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#29E8ED;}
    .st1{display:none;fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st2{fill:#FFFFFF;}
    .st3{fill:#31313D;}
</style>
<rect class="st0" width="2000" height="2000"/>
```

Could it be something weird going on due to the 2000x2000 background?

I have the SVG set to single-scale, which I thought might address the issue by automatically scaling or something similar, but it seems not. Does anyone know how I could fit the image to the screen? Or will I have to manually resize the SVG for each screen size?

[image: Screenshot of the splash screen in question]

Comment: adjust the viewBox values.

Comment: Hey @RobertLongson - I guess that'd work to tailor it to one screen in particular, but does that mean I'd have to have multiple versions of the SVG to tailor to multiple device sizes?

Comment: Also... adjust them how? I've been playing around with it a bit but I can't seem to produce anything that would seem to indicate that it'd end up smaller on the splash screen

Comment: generally if you make the last two values bigger what you see will appear smaller.

Comment: Ah OK - I was trying it out and seeing how it looked in Chrome, which is evidently a bit different than actually on the device itself. I've got it so it's indeed smaller, though now it's oddly stretched. I'll play around with a bit more - I think I've at least seen other SO questions around SVGs being stretched in the same manner

Comment: We're still using a Storyboard for the splash screen, which is odd for an app that's otherwise pure SwiftUI, but we couldn't get the SVG to work right. It seems to me like there should be additional `info.plist` keys beyond just `UIImageRespectsSafeAreaInsets`. For `UIImageView` you can choose `Scale To Fill`, `Aspect Fit`, `Aspect Fill`, `Center`, `Top Left`, and others. These same options should exist for the SVG if you're going to set this purely using `info.plist`.